# Docker and postgresql: server closed the connection unexpectedly (MacOS Catalina)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psql, macos-catalina

I have a simple local environment which includes docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:

  postgres-mydb:
    image: 'postgres:11-alpine'
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: docker_mydb_dev
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
```

Recently when i try to connect to the DB:

```
psql postgresql://user:password@localhost:5433/docker_mydb_dev
```

I get:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

I'm quite stuck and i couldn't find any idea online.

Comment: Is the PostgreSQL server running?

Comment: @jjanes - yes, it runs. But it seems that i'm missing the pg_hba.conf file

Comment: I'd propose to check network interfaces and ports. Is postgres listening on 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: It will not start without that file.  Maybe the file was deleted after it was started.  Or you are looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - to close this issue - the reason i couldn't access my DB (docker or not) was that i was requested to install a firewall on my computer and it blocked the access to localhost. Now everything work as expected.

Thanks for you kind help!

Comment: When popup window came up, I just accepted whatever it was for firewall. After this answer, I checked: docker access for public networks was checked, for Private it was not. Checking that one helped!